# Show next name on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I want to know is a bit basic. I have the following page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<input id="con" value="">
<button id="fab">press</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById("fab").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Jaguar", "Tata"];
    document.getElementById("con").value = cars[0];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here what I want to do is whenever an user clicks on the button, the next array of "cars" should be added in the value field. I don't know how to do this, I did a bit research but couldn't found much help. On page load the value field is empty, on first click it would show "cars[0]", then on second it should show "cars[1]" and so on. I don't know how to do, please help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be one way of doing this. We use the modulus operator but at the same time we assign the result to `idx` so that it won't increase arbitrarily.

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Jaguar", "Tata"],
     idx = -1,
     con = document.getElementById("con");
document.getElementById("fab").addEventListener("click", function(){con.value = cars[idx = ++idx%cars.length]});
```

```html
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<input id="con" value="">
<button id="fab">press</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a counter, and make sure you don't go past the end of the array. You could choose to just go back to the first car after showing the last:

```
<script>
var carCounter = 0;
document.getElementById("fab").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Jaguar", "Tata"];
    document.getElementById("con").value = cars[carCounter % cars.length];
    carCounter++;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a counter variable outside the listener that resets when it reaches the end of the array

```js
var counter = 0;
    cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Jaguar", "Tata"];

document.getElementById("fab").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("con").value = cars[counter];
    counter++;
    if (counter == cars.length){
        counter = 0;
    }
});
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input id="con" value="">
<button id="fab">press</button>
```

Comment: Instead of using an if statement to set the counter back to zero, you could use the modulus operator: `counter %= cars.length`. This should work, although you may need to do `cars.length - 1` instead, I can't remember.